# Hand Truck for Air Travel

Tags: air-travel, luggage

I am planning to take a pair of [24 gallon Rubbermaid action packers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00002N6SQ) as luggage on an airplane.  I would also like to take a hand truck to carry them on before and after checking the action packers.

What kind of hand truck would 
1) carry them both, 
and 2) collapse small enough to fit inside of the action packer?
Where should I look and how can I make sure a product will fit?

Comment: This is way too narrow to be of interest for other users.

Comment: I worried that this could be too narrow. Can this question be edited and salvaged?  I thought about asking, what is the 'best hand truck to take on an airplane' but that seemed too much like an opinion question, which would not fly on some other stackexchange sites (I am clearly new to Travel.)

Comment: Possible alternative: "What characteristics should I look for in a hand truck to take with luggage on a trip?"  Thoughts?

Comment: If I can make a defense for why this is a valuable question (as reworded):  this can be a useful traveling tool, but with a multitude of airplane policies and variance in size allowances, it would be helpful to have guidance on what characteristics to look for.

Comment: I don't get how this is too narrow.  I've wondered about this exact thing.  Particularly because [checking baggage is much cheaper than using a courier](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/10934/3067).  People travel in a variety of different situations.  Sometimes you're moving gear from place to place.  This question should be reopened.

Comment: Can I safely presume you don't mean to take them onboard as carry-on luggage? You intend to check them in, correct? I'm guessing you're after a foldable type - http://www.amazon.com/Magna-Cart-Personal-Hand-Truck/dp/B000HVVSDU

Comment: Not sure why this hasn't been closed yet as opinion based answer but you can look for what you need on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_8?url=search-alias%3Dtools&field-keywords=hand+truck&sprefix=hand+tru%2Ctools%2C460) and if you need to pack it in action packer you will need it to be foldable to it internal dimensions, whatever they might be.

Comment: @uncovery: I don't think it's overly specific. If you generalize from that specific case to that general kind of cases it's actually a fine question.