# Emirates rules regarding cabin baggage and notebooks

Tags: luggage, emirates

Soon I will take a flight with Emirates, my cabin baggage limit is 7kg.

I didn't find a list (if exists) of items you can carry with you outside the cabin baggage.

I will take with me two notebooks, total weight of them is 3.36 kg.

My empty trolley is already 3.5 kg, so if I must put my notebooks inside the cabin baggage I will reach the limit, I would like to take the notebooks (or at least the heavier one) with a pc bag but I don't know if it is permitted by Emirates.

Do you have a link for a list or maybe someone recently took a flight with Emirates and can share the experience?

Comment: As far as I understand it, in economy class, it’s one piece of luggage weighing 7 kg max, full stop. If your empty bag weighs 3.5kg you should probably consider finding a new one.

Comment: Related but useful: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38964/emirates-international-flight-and-carry-on-baggage-can-i-take-a-laptop-backpack?rq=1

Comment: They're more interested in the size of baggage (and the number of bags) because that affects whether it can be stowed onboard, so you'll probably be ok, but if you want to be sure then obey the rules. The degree of checks can depend on where you're flying from, as well as the airline, ticket, busyness, length of flight, etc. In some places airlines examine all carry-on baggage at the gate or on check-in, but this still seems rare. Maybe someone with more experience of Emirates at different airports can expand.

Comment: Airlines rarely weigh your carry-on luggage at the gate, unless you act as if it is heavy. Carry it like it's light, and nobody will ever ask.