# Can I take a 24" computer monitor on board?

Tags: electronic-items, fragile-luggage

I am not a frequent traveler, at least not yet.

I would like to know if a 24" computer monitor in its original box the size of a large luggage would be allowed on board a plane even for an extra charge?

Moreover, I'd like to know what are the safest (and hopefully not expensive) ways I could ship the monitor.

PS: I would prefer to ship it as an extra check-in but I am afraid it gets damaged at some point due to mis-handling especially at the destination airport as I know for a fact that luggage is not well handled at the destination I will be arriving at.

This will be a one-time shipment. And it is one package.

Dimensions as provided by supplied: 53.2 x 35.1 x 4.57 cm (L x H x W)

Weight: ~ 8.5 kg

Item purchased from Amazon.fr: [www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B00OA2I362](http://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B00OA2I362)

PS: Original box has cardboard not foam frame.

Shipping origin: EU

Shipping destination: Middle East.

**alternative idea 1**: I think that taking it as hand luggage without the box would be possible as the monitor can be pivoted in landscape and portrait mode. Moreover the stand can be detached. The main weight is in the stand.
Suggestions for protection and transport bag would be appreciated.

**alternative idea 2**: Detaching the screen and packing it in the luggage between clothes would probably keep it safe? And taking the stand as hand luggage along my backpack.

Comment: Is this a one-time shipment, or will it be re-occurring? I believe the handling differential between airline personnel/equipment and shipper (UPS/DHL) to be minimal, but the shippers will have breakage insurance that possibly the passenger airlines won't?

Comment: If you're shipping overseas (say from the US-UK/EU, or EU-Asia, etc) then your box gets put on a plane no matter whether you take it as luggage or ship it via DHL. The handling (by people and machines) will essentially be the same, give or take. However, the insurance for safe delivery in an unbroken state is likely to be better shipped via commercial carrier, than as luggage. Airlines will accept the requirement it be delivered to the destination airport, not (necessarily) that it remain in one piece.

Comment: EU to Middle East. Dimensions & weight updated.
I understand that (will be on plane). By on-board I mean as hand luggage.

Comment: Are you sure those are the dimensions of the box?  They look like the dimensions of the monitor itself.  If they *are* the dimensions of the box, you should be okay (see http://travel-made-simple.com/carry-on-size-chart/), but if it's really the box then the monitor must be very thin indeed.

Comment: @phoog I contacted the supplied & asked for the shipment dimensions and received those. I suspected that too. As I mentioned the size of the box is nearly the same size as the largest luggage allowed for check-in (not hand luggage).

Comment: updated with alternative ideas.

Comment: Best protection is the original box with the foam inserts designed for it.  In checked bags?  Please don't!  My story:  Laptop in laptop bag, wrapped in towels and clothing, placed in the exact center of bag (clothing on all six sides).  Cinch straps all pulled tight so nothing can move and loose ends tucked into loops on the outside of the bag.  When I claimed the bag, all the straps had been untucked and loosened to full length, some unhooked, and the laptop was on top of everything else, the wrappings removed and stuffed into a corner.

Comment: (continued)  Next trip, I put it in carry-on, but the plane was mall, so they insisted on gate-check.  I removed the laptop first.  Glad I did, because  the handler, instead of sliding the bag onto the belt through the hole (that was apparently designed for that purpose), picked it up over the rail and dropped it onto the belt from about a meter high..

Comment: @WGroleau wow that's not nice at all. I wouldn't want that. My original box doesn't have foam but a frame of carton.

Comment: I would still recommend the original box, but fill the empty spaces with styrofoam or bubble wrap or those heat-sealed airbags that have been available the past few years.  OR, is it small enough (after wrapping) to carry on yourself?

Comment: @user10853: On board a? ...boat? ...train? Please edit your question to add this crucial information.

Answer (score 8):

I successfully managed to bring a 24" monitor home by air traveling, in 2011.
This one:

[image: VH242H]

But of course not in its original, unopened box. Right after I bought it, I was a bit worried: "how could I bring this bad boy home? I definitely don't want to check it. Even with the fragile tag, the panel is way, way too large and too delicate to travel together with other suitcases".

So on my last week before going home, I went to buy a backpack. I asked them for the largest size possible (well, but not too large, not the type you see hitchhiking travelers use). Luckily, the backpack could almost contain the monitor, and when I carry it on, looks not so bad. The monitor is flat and thin anyway.

I kept the monitor in its package for protection purpose till the boarding gate. With the box, the whole thing was so huge that it immediately raised the attention of the man at the check-in counter: "Sir, I notice you're not checking this, you're taking it as a carry on? You're not gonna make it man". But I persuaded him that it will be all right.

At the boarding gate, I threw away the box, attached some small patched to cover the corners and the panels, then I boarded without any problem.

The weight is not a problem. The gate attendants only care if your luggage is small/tidy/compact enough. For a 24" monitor, you cannot take it on-board in the original box, even if you're willing to pay. Its dimensions simply violate the aviation safety regulations.

---

EDIT: And one thing to add, that was 2011, where the airport security was not as strict as today's level (e.g. I never had to pulled out my laptop and my DSLR + set of lens prior to 2012). I put the whole thing (monitor + box) through the X-ray machine at the security gate without a problem, no one asked a question. But these days it will not get through that easily).

Comment: Nice. My monitor's packing is carton and is built for the box. Cannot be used without it and it's sizes up to rh box. Mine can be pivoted in portrait mode. Can you suggest packaging that could protect it if I go with your way? Bubble wrap would do?

Comment: Ironically, the thing is probably safe as houses [in checked luggage](http://www.cyclingweekly.co.uk/news/latest-news/bike-manufacturer-reduces-delivery-damage-70-per-cent-printing-tv-box-285180).

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would say keep it in it's original box, packe it in a large suitcase surrounded by clothes and then check it in.

The original box will be designed to provide padding and support to the monitor in the right places. The suitcase full of clothes provides another layer of padding and makes it less obvious to potential theives what the item is (obviously security will know what it is whatever you do).

Answer (score 2):

This August I traveled with a 27" monitor in checked luggage without any issues. The display was kept in the original box which we wrapped in plastic wrap to protect it and avoid the cardboard box getting damaged should it get wet which can happen if it rains while cargo is being unloaded or loaded.

The original box had Styrofoam at on top and bottom, plus some on the front and back of the monitor, so it was judge adequate and it was, even passing between planes as we did not have a direct flight.

You may want to read these two relevant questions and the top answers:

- [Packing a cardbox box as checked luggage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3983/packing-a-cardbox-box-as-checked-luggage/4173#4173)
- [Can checked baggage on airplanes ever get wet?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53793/can-checked-baggage-on-airplanes-ever-get-wet)

Answer (score 1):

The dimensions you provided are of the panel, not the box. [Official product page](http://accessories.ap.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=hk&cs=hkdhs1&l=en&s=dhs&sku=391-BBUW&redirect=1):

Dimensions without stand (H x W x D):
Height: 13.80" (350.6 mm)
Width: 20.95" (532.2 mm)
Depth: 1.80" (45.7 mm)

I have [written](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/64425/4188) at length about carry on dimensions. Your panel without any packaging is already pushing it. 550 mm is the width usually allowed and the panel is 532.2 mm. The box and packing foam on each side can add 10-10mm and that's it. Also, the 350.6mm will be problematic as some airlines only allow 350mm in the first place but none allows more than 400mm but more typically just 380mm. So you are pushing it but without the box, you are probably good. Bubble wrap is good, handle it carefully. Ask the FA nicely to put it in the clothes cabinet instead of being jostled with the bags in the overhead bin. They just might. If you are in business class, they will be much more willing, that's for sure.

And there's the matter of the stand. That's also a problem: you can only have two pieces of luggage, if you attach the stand then a) it's really unwieldy to move around b) your monitor will be too high and the depth will be a problem too but if you don't then it becomes your personal item and you can't carry anything else really. It probably pushes the dimensions of personal item too but we would need to know the airline to know this. I would rather put the stand in the checked in luggage or mail it.