# Are workstation monitors safe to pack in checked luggage?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, electronic-items

I need to take my monitors for my workstation with me.  Can I pack them in checked luggage? I have two monitors and they are 13 1/2 inches length by 16 inches width.

Comment: See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60591/can-i-take-a-24-computer-monitor-on-board, https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60591/can-i-take-a-24-computer-monitor-on-board.  The answer could depend on the baggage policies of your airline and possibly the specific flight you're taking.

Comment: If you are going to take them onboard and you dont have the original packaging, buy a bit of thin plywood that is the same size as the screen and bezel, put a thin layer of soft foam covering one side, and use masking tape to fix the plywood to cover the screen.  Saves from the panel being scratched or dented by other objects.

Comment: I always had issues with the moderation of this site but closing a question about _checked in_ language as the duplicate of _carrying on_ is something else.

Comment: Not as bad as you indicate, it is likely a honest mistake, those who remembered a question about taking monitors did not see the 'carry-on' and 'checked' when the found the question. Has happened to the best of us. But the question is re-opened now.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I pack them in checked luggage? I have two monitors and they are 13 1/2 inches length by 16 inches width.

I typically travel with two 24-inch monitors in my checked-in suitcase and never had any issue. Tested with a few dozens of flights in North America, South America, Asia and Europe. I use some bubble wraps when time permits, and try to place some soft items (e.g., clothes or towels) facing the screen. One monitor in each side of the suitcase to avoid collision (stand vs. screen shock when the suitcase is thrown around wouldn't be too good). Dettach the monitor stand if possible, though I never had any issue when I kept it.

Please ping me in comment or email if you know any 24-inch monitor weighting less than 2.3kg.

Comment: The AOC E2351F is 23" and 2.5kg and I think it's absolutely impossible to make a lighter weight monitor. I would love to be proven wrong but really, that easel style stand is ridiculously lightweight and the normal stand is barely more than a piece of featherweight plastic, I can measure the stand if you want. My scale won't be able to do the monitor itself but if interested I will borrow a scale and check.

Comment: @chx Thanks very much, 2.5kg including the stand? Last time I went monitor shopping (November 2018), 2.5kg including the stand was indeed the best I could find.

Comment: Yes, including stand and I am intensely curious what other monitor you found at that weight, look at the photos what AOC did to achieve this weight.

Comment: @chx Thanks! See [Ultralight ~24-inch computer monitor](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10010/40) and  [Portable alternatives to conventional LED monitors for coding on two large screens after traveling by plane](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10297/40). I lack knowledge in monitor manufacturing to have any opinion on the feasibility :-) But 16-inch monitors can be  much lighter (<1 kg) e.g. https://smile.amazon.com/Portable-Monitor-Computer-1920%C3%971080-Protector/dp/B07RGPCQG1 (random sampling).

Answer (score 1):

> two monitors of 13 1/2 inches length by 16 inches width

The medium [Geargrip LCD shield](http://www.geargrip.com/details_gglcdb.php) is for a 17.5" x 13.5"-16.5" monitor. Slightly too big but not too bad. When I used to fly with my monitor in my carry on, the glass half of the monitor was always wrapped in one of those and the back of it rested on something soft -- if I bother with a checked in item then I have my pillow with me anyways so that's nice. The lightest monitors you need to protect from back as well, I have destroyed an AOC monitor from the back... but it was DisplayLink so not big of a loss :)

I would also consider whether I could fit these in my carry on, although two is certainly a bit much. This is why I love my old [PackedPixels](https://www.packedpixels.com/): two of them side by side is the same width as a 14" laptop so they fit easily in my personal item but of course they are much smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are. You have to pack them well with a good amount of padding between them and the sides of the suitcases. I have successfully done this several times within a hard-shell suite case. I highly recommend those as they cannot be compressed by more than a few millimeters.

Protect the screen surface with a thin layer of foam and then wrap each monitor separately all around. Tie or tape the wrapping so that it does not get undone in transport. Then make sure the suitcase is full. This is crucial so that the monitors do not bang against each other or other items.

Answer (score 1):

I have two 21 inch monitors that travel wwith me.. I used to pack them very carefully and bubble wrap them.. but now i am lazy about it and i simply have a piecce of cardboard that is the size of the suit case.. I remove stands of course and i make a cardboard sandwich with the monitors being the bread .. I put a layer of clothes at bottom , layer of clothes up top , and try and make sure the monitors have some socks or cushy items around and packed tight so they cant move .. I have airport security ask me once what was in there and i had to go into the luggage area and open to show them .. Other than that no issues and i have done this over a dozen times