# Am I allowed to take a monitor and a Slim PS2 to the UK?

Tags: uk, portugal

It will be my first time flying to another country specifically from Portugal to the UK and i'll be staying as a university student.

I wish to take my 23" monitor and my slim ps2 on my hold luggage as they easly fit however I cannot find any information stating if I'm allowed to do so as the information I found on the UK government website is related to hand luggage only stating if the objects are also allowed or not on the hold luggage and there is no statement on either of this 2 items.

I'm more worried about the monitor than the Ps2 as legally the ps2 is not a console but a computor as I know Sony used this trick to avoid a tax on the EU when they released the product originally.

If anyone has any infromations on either of the 2 objects and on either of the 2 sides of the problem (taking from portugal and taking to the uk) I would be extremly gratefull.

Comment: You should check with your airline whether you can put that monitor in the hold. I'd be worried about it getting damaged. I doubt either Portuguese or UK customs will have a problem with either item.

Comment: You would need to pack these _very_ carefully if you're planning to put them in the hold...and even then, I wouldn't count on them making it intact, especially the monitor.  Hold luggage is not treated gently.  Is there a way you can take them on board with you instead?  Or ship them?  Or simply buy a replacement monitor at your destination, perhaps an inexpensive used one?

Comment: If you take the monitor, put it in its original packaging only. This is the safest way to travel with it. Baggage handlers generally are quite careful with packages which are obviously TVs or displays.

Comment: Not a duplicate but the answers to this question may help in how to pack your items: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/157646/27650

Answer (score 3):

As long as you travel before 31 December 2020, there will be no consequences for customs as the UK and Portugal are both within the EU Customs Union, VAT area, etc, so there are effectivley no restrictions on personal goods between the two countries.

As for if you can travel with such items - the general guidance is to consult your airline's and airports on routes guidance. You haven't specified your airline, so for example see British Airways: https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/baggage-essentials/liquids-and-restrictions

There is no mention of computers, game consoles, monitors or displays as banned or restricted items at all (so you could take them as hold or hand luggage). Anecdotally these are *perfectly normal* things to fly with, although it will be difficult to pack your monitor safely.

Comment: A monitor is essentially half a laptop with a stand. It's bulky, but OP can take the stand off, put that in with their clothes and stick the screen in a laptop bag. Easy.