# Traveling with 24inch monitor

Tags: air-travel, luggage, electronic-items

I bought a BenQ GL2480 monitor, which is a **24 LED MONITOR**. Is putting it in my normal suitcase and covering it with some kind of protection a good idea? What if my suitcase gets scanned in the airport, and the officer realizes I have a monitor in it? Will I get charged, or anything else?

Comment: Since that's not a particularly special monitor, it's worth researching whether it makes more sense to leave it at home and obtain a monitor at your destination. If you have to pay checked bag or excess weight fees because of the monitor, those could easily add up to more than the cost of a similar used (or even new) monitor, though you'd have to factor in the delay and inconvenience of obtaining one. If you know anyone at your destination, you might be able to borrow a spare monitor too.

Comment: There are two questions there: one is the practical aspect of putting the monitor in your suitcase, which is relatively general, the other one about extra charges which may involve taxes and duties. For that one, we need to know the origin and destination, your residency status, your citizenship, the value of the monitor, and whether it’s new or not.

Comment: Also, you need to check that the monitor is compatible with the electricity supply at destination, especially if you love from a 110V country to a 220V country or vice versa.

Comment: @jcaron Nearly all electronics have input ranges that work anywhere on the planet.  It doesn't hurt to check (in this case the GL2480 is 100-240V input), but the overwhelming majority of modern consumer electronics have a universal range.

Comment: Do you still have the original packaging/box?  That was designed to hold and protect that monitor, and is a good choice.  However it would be additional item.

Comment: "Will I get charged...?" <-- needs to specify countries involved.

Comment: I've had to travel with a full tower desktop before.  Biggest issue was weight! watch that.

Comment: Have you considered NOT flying with it? On the occasion I need equipment like that, I have it shipped separately. Most hotels accept that if you talk to them. Easy light travel and you arrive with all your stuff waiting for you, fully insured on top of that. And you can easily use the original packaging to make sure things arrive safely. Yes, costs more. Not that I care when I need it.

Comment: most hotels have a TV in the room that you can use as a monitor, so unless you're sleeping in dorms you don't need to bring a monitor most of the time

Comment: Possible duplicate of "I am flying to Saudi Arabia. How much sand will they let me bring?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I take a 24" computer monitor on board?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60591/can-i-take-a-24-computer-monitor-on-board)

Answer (score 26):

Yes. It is possible to do this safely. The important is to pad the monitor well. Mine  (a 27" NEC) survived inside a suitcase wrapped in towels several times and once in yoga mat. If you monitor has a stand that can be separated, it is best to detach it and wrap separately, as I did notice that it detached once during transport, so luckily it popped out instead of breaking.

Be prepared to answer questions and have to unwrap and re-wrap it several times. The last time I flew with a monitor, I was asked *every* single time to come to security so that they inspect the suitcase with the monitor. This not only included the departure scan but also both stop-overs. One place they even a long argument as to why I would need to be travelling with a monitor. Most times they asked me to unpack it, they inspected it and I was left to pack it again.

You could get charged duties for import if it looks new and that really depends on your arrival country and agreement with the country of purchase or manufacture. It is not possible to know what duty you will need to pay without knowing more. For example, as a Canadian, there is a duty-free allowance that I am allowed to bring back, depending on the duration of my stay abroad and some monitors are below that allowance, in which case no duty is required but a receipt is requested to determine this at the point of entry. If it costs more than the allowance, I would be asked to pay duties on the *entire* amount, not just the excess. Check duties and exceptions for you point of import.

Comment: "I was asked every single time to come to security so that they inspect the suitcase with the monitor" carry-on or check-in? Never happened to me in check-in, mostly flying in US and Asia.

Comment: Checked luggage. 27" wouldn't fit in carry-on on most airlines.  It's quite cumbersome to have checked-luggage inspected. You get called to the counter, escorted to a secure area, wait along with whoever else has been called, go through the inspection and then get escorted back. Even happened when I transported the monitor in its original box instead of a suitcase, in which case it's good idea to pack extra tape too. Got inspected in the US too, Canada, Central and South America but I didn't travel to Asia with a monitor yet.

Comment: Thanks, interesting, is your monitor metallic? Mine is 24 inch and cheap plastic, never attracted security.

Comment: All my monitors are high-end and I flew last with a 27" and before that with a 24" model. They outer-frame is plastic but I don't know what they look like through and X-ray. Although, twice I traveled with it in its original box and had to open it too. So, even when they clearly knew what was inside the box, it didn't stop them from asking me to open it and then *I* had to ask them for tape! Next time, I packed the tape in the box itself.

Comment: Correction, one of them has a metal front frame and both have metal stands. Most of the body and the back panel of both monitors are plastic.

Comment: `Mine (a 27" NEC) survived inside a suitcase wrapped in towels several times and once in yoga mat.` Having seen the soaring parabolic arcs that checked luggage are subjected to, I'm frankly amazed.

Comment: The countries you are travelling to/from also matter. Travelling via countries like Italy I wouldn't leave the monitor open for inspection. If the monitor with some protection is wrapped in a sealed plastic bag security people can check the luggage with a scanner, but baggage handler wouldn't be able to understand what it is. Lost luggages and stolen objects happen quite often.

Comment: People used to fly with all sorts of fun electronics. I worked for a firm that used a ruggedized rack unit over a metre cube and weighting maybe 80kg. Was in the excess baggage line for that behind a news crew headed to a war zone with many even larger boxes, satellite terminals, etc.

Comment: Import duties are a good point to mention. Monitors may not be expensive enough to fall under many countries' rules, but it's worth bringing a receipt of some sort (even if it's a print-out from an online order) so you can prove the item's value. On a return journey (back to where you bought it) it can also prove you aren't importing the item and don't need to pay duty. (As an aside, monitors are pretty fragile, speaking as someone who recently banged the top of one while moving it.)

Comment: It really depends. All my monitors are quite expensive and so they would require duty in most places but more importantly, even *cheap monitors* by North American standards can be considered luxury items when flying to poor countries.

Answer (score 11):

Done it, works fine in checked luggage, but you need something to avoid pressure on the display surface itself or you're risking dead pixels.

If you only have one monitor, the best thing I could think of would be a wooden board (ideally something like MDF) taped to the front. For two monitors, I've usually taped them together so their screens face each other.

Answer (score 7):

> BenQ GL2480 monitor which is 24 LED MONITOR so the idea of putting it in my normal suitecase and cover it with some kind of protection will be a good idea?

Yes. I actually never had any issue even when not using any protection, but doesn't hurt to add protection, esp. on the screen side, if you have time for it when packing (I typically casually put some bubble wrap around it, it takes me ca. one minute per screen). Just make sure there are no hard objects next to the screen, eg avoid putting a weight next to it.

> what if my suitecase got scanned in the airport and the officer relized it is a monitor i willnot get charged or anything??

No.

Source: I traveled dozens of times with a cheap 24-inch monitor (typically two) in my check-in luggage. It never attracted the attention of the security team or customs.

[image]

FYI: [Ultralight ~24-inch computer monitor](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10010/40).

Comment: Thanks for the portable tips link!

Answer (score 5):

I have carried a Dell U2417H from New York to New Delhi with a layover in Paris.

How I packed?

- Wrap with two layers of bubble-wrap.
- Lay a thicker cloth at the base of suitcase
- Cushioned edge of suitcase with softer clothes
- Keep the monitor on it
- Keep remaining softer clothes.

The formula is keeping in mind that airport workers do throw suitcases sometimes.

Comment: I've flown around with that same screen. It's been fine.

Answer (score 4):

I've travelled with a monitor in the checked luggage. It was a somewhat bulky flat-screen from late 2000s. I have to say, I was totally expecting it to not survive the flight since I received it kind of as a gift - the person was going to throw it away. To my surprise it worked afterwards and still works to this day. It was a return flight so the monitor was wrapped in a lot of dirty clothing as to cushion it. With today's fragile ultra slim displays that crackle when you hold them the wrong way? I wouldn't risk it.

As for security, nobody asked anything and I didn't see any signs that the bag had been opened. It was in Schengen Area so your experience may differ.

Answer (score 1):

I used to fly regularly -- as in, hundreds of flights over many years -- with a monitor in checked in luggage and the only safe way I found is to use a geargrip shield with the shield covering the glass and the back of the monitor lying on my trusty pillow (which I haul around anyways because I like sleeping comfortably). Either this or the original box can work but too often the original box is not suitable for flying.

Yes, your monitor *can* be broken from the back, I had one to break so. Inside a hardshell, no less. You need to protect front and back both and have a shield which is larger than glass so it can't bump on the side either.

Wrapping a monitor in a towel or two is just asking for disaster. Bubble wrap in my experience gets too bulky by the time you assure the sides are protected too.

This, of course, only applies if you are interested in a semi-DIY light weight and relatively cheap solution inside a suitcase. GATOR, Pelican etc have excellent premade solutions that protect your monitor from pretty much anything (short of high explosives). I did try flying with a Pelican and I was satisfied with the protection but I was less satisfied with the weight (go figure).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would probably not bother taking a $150 USD monitor in an airplane (though I can imagine circumstances where it might be necessary). If you don't have the original box (or don't want to use it because it makes it look new), I would suggest packing the monitor with something rigid in front of and taped to the screen if you don't have hard-sided luggage.

If you can get ahold of some foamcore (plastic foam sandwiched between two sheets of cardboard, used for graphic arts etc.) two or three layers of 3/16" thick hot glued together may be sufficient.

I have traveled with some fairly heavy/bulky electronics, a couple years ago I went out to a radiation testing facility on the Canadian West Coast with a couple computers, power supplies test equipment, test jigs, space rated electromechanical assemblies and so on, total more than 80kg packed into Pelican cases and one heavy corrugated carton. It was quite straightforward, though the electronics cost about one extra ticket to bring.

Pelican cases are great, but not cheap and even a knock-off might not be as inexpensive as ordering a monitor on Amazon or equivalent for shipment to your end destination.