# Monitor in Checked Luggage - Damage by Vibration/Shaking?

Tags: luggage, damaged-luggage

I'm about to travel with a 27" Monitor in it's original packing. I don't have any fears of it hitting another hard object and breaking that way, but I wonder if it can be damaged "by its own weight" by turning/shaking and so on? (The bag will undoubtley be thrown/put upside down etc.

Monitor: LG 27GL83A 27

Comment: Likely will be fine. [Traveling with 24inch monitor](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163747/traveling-with-24inch-monitor)

Answer (score 1):

It the monitor is in it’s original manufacturer’s packaging (foam and box), it should be fine. That packaging is designed for shipping from the (probably overseas) manufacturer to distributor to store/website to end user. That’s more vibration/banging/etc that you are likely to see in aircraft checked luggage.